# how to store random generated integers into string?

Tags: c++, string, int, store

I have a function that generats 15 integers between (0,1).
how can I store these generated integers into string and treat them as string?

This is my code, str contains symbols when I cout it. 
an help   ? 
****************========== 000000000000000000

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  string str;

  for(int i = 0; i<15; i++){
    int random =  rand()%2 ; 
    cout<< random ; 
    str += random ;
  }
  cout<<str ; 

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many integers is there between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str += random ? "1" : "0";
```

This only works when there are two choices for `random` - if more values are possible then you need a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

use std::stringstream:

```
std::stringstream ss;

for(int i = 0; i<15; i++){
    int random = rand()%2; 
    ss << random; 
}

std::string str = ss.str();
```